# What is the point of PostLogoutRedirectUri in Open Id/OAuth2.0 logout?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, logout, angular-auth-oidc-client

I've been using Identity Server 4.0 as my OpenId Connect provider. I can setup clients in Identity Server with Redirect Uris and Post Logout Redirect Uris. I've also been using the angular-auth-oidc-client to login/logout via the Identity server.

When logging in, my client library (angular-auth-oidc-client) does pass in the correct Uri specified in the config when calling the authorize endpoint. When I try to login with an incorrect Redirect Uri, Identity Server checks and validates that the Uri provided by the client is one of the accepted one for that client, and shows an error if it isnt (as expected).

When it comes to logout, none of it seems to be built in. My client library does not send the PostLogoutRedirectUri when calling the logout endpoint. Identity Server's sample code for logout does not except any URIs to be passed in. It's sample code simply gets the Post Logout Redirect Uri value from the database and creates a link on the logged out page. Not only does the sample code not allow the user to specify the Redirect Uri for logout, but it doesn't do any checks or even do a redirect (granted its only sample code and I can change it). I would expect my client library to pass the Uri along and Identity Server to redirect to the Uri after successful logout as long as its one of the "approved" Uris for the client.

**My question is:** What even is the point of PostLogoutRedirectUri? Neither Identity Server nor the OIDC client library I'm using do anything useful with it. There doesn't even seem to be an agreed upon convention for the name of the query string parameters to use to pass this Uri to Identity Server. And yet, both the Identity Server and the angular client library seem to have some support for it. So what's the point of this thing? Is it something that will be added or fleshed out later? Did I miss some documentation describing what its for and how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a draft standard and support differs between libraries and vendors, but here is a summary:

- A client uses the post logout redirect URI to log out in a controlled way, typically redirecting to an application page that gives the user a link to sign in again
- A client could potentially have more than one post_logout_redirect_uri and decide which to use based on runtime conditions
- The post_logout_redirect_uri sent is meant to only be honoured if it is accompanied by an id_token_hint - and if it matches a configured value against the OAuth client. I believe OIDC will send the current id token but it is worth checking that this is happening in your browser tools.
- If a post_logout_redirect_uri is not sent then the Authorization Server may use the default one configured

See the [official IETF docs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#RedirectionAfterLogout) on how this is meant to work.

Answer (score 1):

In my own application, I set it to the **/Signout-callback-oidc** URL of the client, like

```
PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/signout-callback-oidc" },
```

The **/signout-callback-oidc** path is defined as in the source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// The request path within the application's base path where the user agent will be returned after sign out from the identity provider.
/// See post_logout_redirect_uri from http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RedirectionAfterLogout.
/// </summary>
public PathString SignedOutCallbackPath { get; set; }
```

I hope this can give some clarification.

Comment: Question: What page is shown to the user on logout? How do they log back in?

Answer (score -1):

There are two sessions, one in the UI, and another on the server.  It might need to call a URL on the backend to remove the user session on the server, otherwise the server won't know you are logged out on the UI.

Comment: It's not about the end session url, but about the redirect. Maybe you should consider reading the question more thoroughly again